# How to replace a push with a splice js

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

When entering a screen, 5 promises are loaded automatically, I use a promise.all, the problem is that they are executed randomly, within each function I use a push where I put the information.

The problem is that I have to change the push for a splice because the promise.all is loaded randomly and with the push I can't know which place to assign to each information of each "function". Here is my code:

At the beginning it loads the promises

```
ngOnInit(): void {
Promise.all([this.getData1(), this.getData2()]).then(values => {
            console.log(values)
            this.processing = true;
          }).catch(reason => {
            console.log('error get data',reason)
          });
}
```

I only put 2 as an example but in the other functions it is the same

```
 public getData1() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.createService.getServiceData1().subscribe(
                (response: any) => {
                    let customFieldOption: CustomFieldOption = new CustomFieldOption();
                    this.opcionServicio = response;
                    this.opcionesServicio.push(this.opcionServicio);
                    this.servicio.push(this.opcionesServicio[0].ticket_field.title)
                    customFieldOption.id = this.opcionServicio.ticket_field.id;
                    customFieldOption.name = this.opcionServicio.ticket_field.title;
                    this.customFieldOptions.push(customFieldOption);
                    resolve(true);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(true);
                }
            );
        });
    }




 public getData2() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.createService.getServiceData2().subscribe(
                    (response: any) => {
                        let customFieldOption: CustomFieldOption = new CustomFieldOption();
                        this.opcionServicio = response;
                        this.opcionesServicio.push(this.opcionServicio);
                        this.servicio.push(this.opcionesServicio[0].ticket_field.title)
                        customFieldOption.id = this.opcionServicio.ticket_field.id;
                        customFieldOption.name = this.opcionServicio.ticket_field.title;
                        this.customFieldOptions.push(customFieldOption);
                        resolve(true);
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(true);
                    }
                );
            });
        }
```

Comment: You'll have a better chance getting a useful answer here if you can provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now it's all errors because we don't have access to your code base; consider creating a new small code example from scratch that shows the problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array with indexes instead of `push` or an object with static keys.

Example 1:

You can put `data1` to `this.opcionesServicio[0]` and `data2` to `this.opcionesServicio[1]`. Then you know that they can be always accessed by the same index.

```js
 opcionesServicio = [];

 public getData1(dataIndex = 0) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.createService.getServiceData1().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.opcionesServicio[dataIndex] = respoosne;
     });
   });
 }

 public getData2(dataIndex = 1) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.createService.getServiceData2().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.opcionesServicio[dataIndex] = respoosne;
     });
   });
 }

// Access
const data1 = this.opcionesServicio[0];
const data2 = this.opcionesServicio[1];
```

Example 2:

You can store the data in an object instead.
`data1` goes to `this.opcionesServicio['data1']` and `data2` to `this.opcionesServicio['data2']`. Then you can access them by the `data1`, `data2` keys.

```js
 opcionesServicio = {};

 public getData1(dataName = 'data1') {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.createService.getServiceData1().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.opcionesServicio[dataName] = respoosne;
     });
   });
 }

 public getData2(dataName = 'data2') {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.createService.getServiceData2().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.opcionesServicio[dataName] = respoosne;
     });
   });
 }

const data1 = this.opcionesServicio['data1'];
const data2 = this.opcionesServicio['data2'];
```